# Using rail to generate syntax diagram with curly brackets as terminal symbols

Tags: symbols, diagrams

Using [rail](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/rail) I try to generate a syntax diagramm that has to include curly brackets. For everything else, rail works fine for me but whenever i try something like:

```
    \begin{rail}        
    DefiningQuery: 
    '\textbraceleft' + 'B'
    \end{rail}
```

it generatetes the following .rai file:

```
    \rail@i{1}{ DefiningQuery: '\T1\textbraceleft ' + 'B' }
```

and this .rao file:

```
    % This file was generated by 'rail' from 'Thesis.rai'
    \rail@i {1}{ DefiningQuery: '\T1\textbraceleft ' + 'B' }
    \rail@o {1}{
    \rail@begin{2}{DefiningQuery}
    \rail@plus
    \rail@term{\T1\textbraceleft }[]
    \rail@nextplus{1}
    \rail@cterm{B}[]
    \rail@endplus
    \rail@end
    }
```

Sadly trying to build my latex document with this .rao file results only in this:

[image: output]

Does anyone has an idea on how I can fix this or how to use curly brackets correctly with [rail](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/rail)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if you define the curly braces as terminal identifiers as described in [section 4.2 of the ReadMe](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/rail/rail.ps):

```
\railalias{lbrace}{\{}
\railalias{rbrace}{\}}
\railterm{lbrace,rbrace}

\begin{rail}    
    DefiningQuery: 
   lbrace + 'B'
\end{rail}
```